# Combination of CellPrint and PrintTemporary, or DisplayForm for Cells

Tags: programming, front-end, output-formatting, boxes

I'm programmatically generating some formatted output that generates a cell in the form of a `Cell[]` expression. For instance, the output might be

```
cell = Cell[TextData[{"Function ",
    Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"f","(","x",")"}],
        TraditionalForm]], FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]}],
   "Subsection"];
```

(where $f(x)$ will actually be some complicated expression). **How can I get the rendered `Cell` expression displayed in the notebook temporarily during evaluation?**

I can display it (permanently) in the notebook using `CellPrint`:

[image: CellPrint]

I can display text temporarily using `PrintTemporary`:

[image: PrintTemporary]

But combining them doesn't work, because `PrintTemporary` assumes its argument is an expression to print rather than a box structure:

[image: PrintTemporary doesn't work]

Adding `DisplayForm` doesn't work; it seems `DisplayForm` only works for boxes when not wrapped in a complete `Cell` expression:

[image: DisplayForm doesn't work]

So I really need a `CellPrintTemporary` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be possible to produce the Cell dingbat et al, as those don't appear on inline cells.  However, you can at least get the formatting of your Cell expression by preventing it from being converted to Box form (doubly, making it inert).

Here is a practical example:

```
myPrintTemp[expr_Cell] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{MakeBoxes},
  MakeBoxes[expr, _] := expr;
  PrintTemporary[expr]
 ]

myPrintTemp[cell]; Pause[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes) to render a [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) object:

```
PrintTemporary[RawBoxes @ cell]; Pause[2]
```

[image]