# Notebook vs. DocumentNotebook; display a Notebook inline, like a DocumentNotebook

Tags: programming, notebooks, output-formatting, formatting, boxes

If you evaluate a [`DocumentNotebook[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/DocumentNotebook.html) expression in the front-end, it nicely displays inline, inside of an output cell in the current notebook:

[image: DocumentNotebook displayed]

For my purposes, `TextCell` and `ExpressionCell` expressions are insufficiently flexible. So (as in the question [Combination of CellPrint and PrintTemporary, or DisplayForm for Cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25520/combination-of-cellprint-and-printtemporary-or-displayform-for-cells)), I'm programmatically generating some formatted output that generates raw `Cell[]` box expressions. For instance, the output might be

```
cell = Cell[TextData[{"Function ",
    Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"f","(","x",")"}],
        TraditionalForm]], FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]}],
   "Subsection"];
```

(where $f(x)$ will actually be some complicated expression).

Unfortunately, `DocumentNotebook[]` seems to require `TextCell`/`ExpressionCell` and doesn't work when given `Cell[]`s:

[image: DocumentNotebook with Cell]

So I tried using [`Notebook[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/Notebook.html) instead, which does work with `Cell[]`s. However, evaluating a `Notebook` expression doesn't display in the front-end:

[image: Notebook]

It displays correctly when I run `NotebookPut@Notebook@{cell}`, but in a new window. **How can I get it to display inline in the current notebook, like how `DocumentNotebook` displays?** I tried wrapping it in `CellPrint` and in `DisplayForm`, but those don't work for `Notebook[]`s.

Relatedly, what's the difference between `DocumentNotebook` ([and](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/PaletteNotebook.html) [friends](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/DialogNotebook.html)) and `Notebook`? Both appear to be intended to represent a notebook as an expression, but as I discovered they behave slightly differently.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I don't know an answer off the top of my head and I gotta go sleep. But try `cell = TextCell[Row[{"Function ", ExpressionCell[TraditionalForm@Defer@f[x]]}],   "Subsection"]`

Comment: Would you mind getting rid of the brackets in the question title? They make reading it quite hard and do not clarify as such - most readers will recognize the functions anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps it's not obvious because this doesn't look like a box.  But the way that `DocumentNotebook`, et al, get translated into `Notebook` is by going through `MakeBoxes`.  Which means that `RawBoxes` saves the day by preserving its guts in `MakeBoxes`:

```
DocumentNotebook@{TextCell["Hello world!", "Section"], RawBoxes@cell, 
  TextCell["The solution is:", "Text"]}
```

Comment: Greaaaaaaaaaat!!

Comment: +1 Is there a way to remove the border and button?  `Options[DocumentNotebook]` seems to bring up a lot of options but I don't see anything specific there or in the docs.

Comment: In case anyone is interested [the following](http://pastebin.com/u2sX8EYY) automatically wraps the cells with RawBoxes and then removes the border and button to print as a single cell.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite tested

```
embeddedNotebookForm/:
MakeBoxes[embeddedNotebookForm[nb:Notebook[cells_List,___]],StandardForm]:=
    MakeBoxes@DocumentNotebook[{TextCell@"tag"}]/.{
        {{Cell["tag"]}}:>Block[{},List/@
            Replace[cells,
                Cell[CellGroupData[{cs__Cell},_]]:>cs, {1}]
                /;True],
    _Notebook|_DocumentNotebook:>nb}
```

So you would do `Notebook[...]//embeddedNotebookForm`

Example, try `NotebookGet[]//embeddedNotebookForm` in some notebook with stuff

Comment: @Silvia, but that is not a proper `Notebook[...]` expression. Try to `NotebookPut` that and you'll get errors too

Comment: Ah.. I see.. `TextCell[..]` is NOT a `Cell` expression! +1

Comment: BTW I'm always wonder would it be possible to realize a nested `Notebook`, which serves like the *minipage* environment in LaTeX.

Comment: @Rojo very nice, but I had to change `Replace[cells,Cell[CellGroupData[{cs__Cell},_]]:>cs, {1}]` to `(cells //. Cell[CellGroupData[{cs__Cell}, _]] :> cs) `

Comment: @RolfMertig thanks and nice catch. It's probably better to replace it with `FixedPoint[
 Replace[#, Cell[CellGroupData[{cs__Cell}, _]] :> cs, {1}] &, cells]` though

Comment: @Rojo ¡Si, señor!

Comment: @Rojo, why would it be better to use `FixedPoint[Replace[#,rule]&,expr]` instead of `ReplaceRepeated[expr,rule]`?

Comment: @TimothyWofford because `ReplaceRepeated` will work at all levels, so if you have some Cell expressions somewhere deep inside (such as in the output of `Dynamic[Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell["a"], Cell["b"]},Open]]]` it will bet wrongly replaced

Answer (score 2):

Another solution involves messing with the box structure directly.

This is just a basic example but `GridBox` accepts as argument cells of the form `{{cell}..}`.  In fact this is what `DocumentNotebook` actually outputs Cells inside of a `GridBox`.  Column and Row both use `GridBox` internally also.

A simple example would be.

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[
   GridBox[{{
        Cell[BoxData["test"], "Input"]
      }}
    ]], "Output"]
```

Creating a function with MakeBoxes allows you to accept a list of cells like so.  You need to use a Replace to make sure that the code works for `CellGroupData` because `GridBox` doesn't support such and returning an empty string when the Cell list is empty.

```
CellList /: MakeBoxes[CellList[list_], form_] := If[
  Length[list] > 0,
  GridBox[Map[{#} &,
    Replace[
     list
     , Cell[CellGroupData[{x___}, ___]] :> (x), {0, 1}
     ]
    ]],
  ""
  ];
```

And print cells like so.

```
CellList[{
  Cell[BoxData["1"], "Input"],
  Cell[BoxData["2"], "Input"],
  Cell[CellGroupData[{
    Cell[BoxData["a"], "Input"],
    Cell[BoxData["a"], "Output"]
   }, Open]]
}]
```